# error in else if rows? Is there a more concise way of writing this?

Tags: php, if-statement

My code selects from the database, writes out the information then runs an else if loop to decide what code to output:

```
<?php

echo '<p>the loop<p><br>
 <p>Accreditations</p>';

      if ($fields['accreditations1']==1){echo 'HTML CODE 1';} else { 
      if ($fields['accreditations1']==2){echo 'HTML CODE 2';} else { 
      if ($fields['accreditations1']==3){echo 'HTML CODE 3';} else { 
      if ($fields['accreditations1']==4){echo 'HTML CODE 4';} else { 
      if ($fields['accreditations1']==5){echo 'HTML CODE 5';} else { 
      if ($fields['accreditations1']==6){echo 'HTML CODE 6';} else { 
      if ($fields['accreditations1']==7){echo 'HTML CODE 7';} else { 
      if ($fields['accreditations1']==0){echo '';}

      if ($fields['accreditations2']==1){echo 'HTML CODE 1';} else { 
      if ($fields['accreditations2']==2){echo 'HTML CODE 2';} else { 
      if ($fields['accreditations2']==3){echo 'HTML CODE 3';} else { 
      if ($fields['accreditations2']==4){echo 'HTML CODE 4';} else { 
      if ($fields['accreditations2']==5){echo 'HTML CODE 5';} else { 
      if ($fields['accreditations2']==6){echo 'HTML CODE 6';} else { 
      if ($fields['accreditations2']==7){echo 'HTML CODE 7';} else { 
      if ($fields['accreditations2']==0){echo '';}

      if ($fields['accreditations3']==1){echo 'HTML CODE 1';} else { 
      if ($fields['accreditations3']==2){echo 'HTML CODE 2';} else { 
      if ($fields['accreditations3']==3){echo 'HTML CODE 3';} else { 
      if ($fields['accreditations3']==4){echo 'HTML CODE 4';} else { 
      if ($fields['accreditations3']==5){echo 'HTML CODE 5';} else { 
      if ($fields['accreditations3']==6){echo 'HTML CODE 6';} else { 
      if ($fields['accreditations3']==7){echo 'HTML CODE 7';} else { 
      if ($fields['accreditations3']==0){echo '';}

      echo '<br />';

      if ($fields['accreditations4']==1){echo 'HTML CODE 1';} else { 
      if ($fields['accreditations4']==2){echo 'HTML CODE 2';} else { 
      if ($fields['accreditations4']==3){echo 'HTML CODE 3';} else { 
      if ($fields['accreditations4']==4){echo 'HTML CODE 4';} else { 
      if ($fields['accreditations4']==5){echo 'HTML CODE 5';} else { 
      if ($fields['accreditations4']==6){echo 'HTML CODE 6';} else { 
      if ($fields['accreditations4']==7){echo 'HTML CODE 7';} else { 
      if ($fields['accreditations4']==0){echo '';}

      if ($fields['accreditations5']==1){echo 'HTML CODE 1';} else { 
      if ($fields['accreditations5']==2){echo 'HTML CODE 2';} else { 
      if ($fields['accreditations5']==3){echo 'HTML CODE 3';} else { 
      if ($fields['accreditations5']==4){echo 'HTML CODE 4';} else { 
      if ($fields['accreditations5']==5){echo 'HTML CODE 5';} else { 
      if ($fields['accreditations5']==6){echo 'HTML CODE 6';} else { 
      if ($fields['accreditations5']==7){echo 'HTML CODE 7';} else { 
      if ($fields['accreditations5']==0){echo '';}

      if ($fields['accreditations6']==1){echo 'HTML CODE 1';} else { 
      if ($fields['accreditations6']==2){echo 'HTML CODE 2';} else { 
      if ($fields['accreditations6']==3){echo 'HTML CODE 3';} else { 
      if ($fields['accreditations6']==4){echo 'HTML CODE 4';} else { 
      if ($fields['accreditations6']==5){echo 'HTML CODE 5';} else { 
      if ($fields['accreditations6']==6){echo 'HTML CODE 6';} else { 
      if ($fields['accreditations6']==7){echo 'HTML CODE 7';} else { 
      if ($fields['accreditations6']==0){echo '';}

      ?>
```

Firstly do I need to do something to close the ifs? Also is there a shorter way of doing this?

Comment: What's seen can't be unseen... Indeed, why use functions when one can type fast?

Comment: THE GOGGLES THEY DO NOTHING! Consider using a [switch](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`switch` statement](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php), like this

```
switch( $fields['accreditations1'] ) {
  case 1: echo 'HTML CODE 1'; break;
  case 2: echo 'HTML CODE 2'; break;
  case 3: echo 'HTML CODE 3'; break;
  case 4: echo 'HTML CODE 4'; break;
  case 5: echo 'HTML CODE 5'; break;
  case 6: echo 'HTML CODE 6'; break;
  case 7: echo 'HTML CODE 7'; break;
  case 0: echo '';
}
```

<sup>I assume, that is not the actual output. If I am mistaken, you should consider writing a separate function for this!</sup>

Comment: In fact, if it's indeed OMG OMG 1, 2, 3 etc... strings to echo, even switch will be considered a DailyWTF material - but vastly inferior to that given in the question, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, using a `for` loop,

```
 for( $i=1; $i<=count($fields); $i++) {
   if( $fields['accreditations'.$i] > 0 && $fields['accreditations'.$i] <= 7)
     echo 'HTML CODE ' $fields['accreditations'.$i];  
 }
```

Comment: But what if that expression is `8`, for example? ) Strictly speaking, you have to check for `<= 7` for this to completely match the code in question, I suppose. AND there's also a <br /> in the middle of that loop...

Comment: Yeah, I wanted to write something like this, but I doubt all those HTML fragments are indeed that. I think it's just an example.

Comment: @raina77ow: agreed, considering that this is the entire code.

Answer (score 1):

I think you got a `'` too many after `<p>Accreditations</p>`.

Apart from that, you can use a switch statement which will shorten this code a little.

You can also use:

```
if (condition) {}
else if (othercondition) {}
elseif (thirdcondition {}
else {}
```

Note that the if of the else is *not inside* the brackets of the else. You can write `else if` or `elseif`, both mean the same.

That is especially useful in cases where a switch doesn't work. In your case, just use a switch.

Comment: In fact, since now I have a luxury of working with 5.3, sometimes I express switches in associative array (`'scenario1' => function() { behaviour1; }`, etc.). It allows reusing the code later.

Comment: @raina77ow Nice trick, but it won't help this code in any way.